# How to display multiple lines in UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Tags: ios, tableview, cell

So I have a download manager in my app. I have taken it upon myself to liven it up today.

I have implemented UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle, and is displaying properly.

I want to add more than 1 line to it. Right now I'm stuck in choosing either the file size or the formatted date.

How would I do both? i.e.

```
Cell Title
Date: (followed by file size) or
File Size:
```

Below is the relevant code I'm working with.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [(UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
        }

    // Configure the cell.
        cell.textLabel.text = [directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:30/255.0 green:30/255.0 blue:30/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
        [cell.layer setBorderWidth:1.5f];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;


    //Get file size
        NSError *error;
        NSString *fileName = [directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my folder"];
        path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error];
        NSInteger fileSize = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize] intValue];

    //Setting the date
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my folder"];
        filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        NSDate *creationDate = nil;
        NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
        creationDate = attributes[NSFileCreationDate];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
        NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:creationDate];


/////This is where I need to blend the dateString with the file size//////
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:dateString, @"%@", [self formattedFileSize:fileSize]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

        return cell;
    }
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this out, and for some reason, setting numberOfLines to 2 didn't work for me either, but setting it to anything greater then 2, or setting it to 0 worked.

You need to format your two strings properly. This is not correct syntax,

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:dateString, @"%@", [self formattedFileSize:fileSize]]
```

It should be like this,

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",  dateString, [self formattedFileSize:fileSize]];
```

Comment: Yah I tried using cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2 as well with no luck. I guess I need to figure out how to set this properly. cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:dateString, @"%@", [self formattedFileSize:fileSize]]. With that date string in there, it will show the date, but the file size code gets left out.

Comment: @ChrisOSX, Do you mean you tried 3? Try 0, and see if that works.

Comment: @ChrisOSX, Where are you trying to add both strings to the detail label? I only see you setting the file size. You need to concatenate the two strings into one with a "\n" in between to make the second part of the string go to the second line.

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:dateString, @"%@", [self formattedFileSize:fileSize]]; is where it's being added. Maybe I'm using \n wrong I don't know. I've seen it be used in regular text format, but not with text thats pulling actual file data.

Comment: @ChrisOSX You should add that code (the formattedFileSize: method) to your question then, since that's probably where the problem is.

Comment: There isn't a problem with that piece of my code. If I take out dateString from: [NSString stringWithFormat:dateString, @"%@", [self formattedFileSize:fileSize]]; it displays the file size. If I take out: @"%@", [self formattedFileSize:fileSize] and just leave dateString, it shows the formatted date. I'm looking to use both.

Comment: The problem is with that statement -- the syntax is incorrect. I've updated my answer to add the correct syntax.

Comment: Figured it out and posted my answer, only to realize after I refreshed, you posted the same thing :) Credit to you good sir and thanks for helping me think this out.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. Just had to tweak around with the format of the string.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", dateString, [self formattedFileSize:fileSize]];
```

As posting this answer the page refreshed and seen that rdelmar is also correct in his updated post showing the proper syntax.

Credit and thanks to him for the help in helping me think this out.